# Create new element by jQuery each time ajax is triggered

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I am struggling with the idea of, adding elements to DOM for each time I triggered an AJAX call by jQuery.

I just want to ask if this is a possible solution or I should not do it through AJAX if I want elements each time I triggered an event.

The code below refresh the text everytime I triggered the AJAX call, I want it to add whole new element instead of refreshing.

BTW here is the code I have written.

```
function successAJAX(response){
        response = $.parseJSON(response);
        var priceHTML = document.createElement('p');
        priceHTML.innerText= "foo";
        $("#priceContainer").append(priceHTML);
    }
```

Comment: So what isn't working about your code?

Comment: please explain in detail about ur situation

Comment: Sorry about my bad English.
The problem is I can't stack the new element each time I called an AJAX function. For example, when I trigger 100 times ajax, I expect 100 new elements will appear, and the real situation is it only refresh each time I trigger the ajax function. Thank you for pointing out my ambiguity.